# Quill editor italic text is red

Tags: javascript, quill, italic

I am using Quill editor with snow theme, according to the [theme playground](https://quilljs.com/standalone/snow/) the italic text should be black and not red, yet when i use it the text color is red.

My code:

```
const editor = new Quill('#editor', {
        theme: 'snow'
});
```

I also included these

```
<!-- Main Quill library -->
<script src="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.min.js"></script>

<!-- Theme included stylesheets -->
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.bubble.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Here is how it looks on my site:
[Picture showing red italic text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXoej.png)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Quill uses `<em>` tags for italic text. Then i found this in an auto-generated 10k line long css file:

```
/*
* Emphasize
*/
em {
  color: #f0506e;
}
```